# Need to load an aspx page on broswer close event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi I Need to load an aspx page on broswer close event . I tried the following code. But it does not seem to work. Can anyone help me out with this. Thanks

```
 var clicked = false;
    function CheckBrowser() {
        if (clicked == false) {
            //Browser closed   
        } else {
            //redirected
            clicked = false;
        }
    }
    function bodyUnload() {
        alert(1);
        alert(clicked);
        if (clicked == false)//browser is closed  
        {
            alert(clicked);
            var request = GetRequest();
            request.open("POST", "..Security/Logout.aspx", false);
            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send();
        }
    }

    function GetRequest() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean `it does not seem to work`? What exactly is happening? Are you getting any error?

Comment: I am not getting redirected to the page Security/Logout.aspx on browser close

Comment: You are making POST request to the log out page. You are not redirecting. Are checking if it's not redirecting by observing how many alerts you are seeing?

Comment: I can see three alerts

Comment: As I said you are not redirecting. You are making POST request to Logout.aspx so you won't see that happening in UI. You can put a break point in code behind of Logout.aspx and check if it's executing. You can use fiddler to see what requests are being made .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
request.open("POST", "..Security/Logout.aspx", false);
```

Maybe you can try

```
window.location = "..Security/Logout.aspx";
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and my issue was resolved

```
var clicked = false;

    function bodyUnload() {
        alert(1);
        if (clicked == false)//browser is closed  
        {
            var request = GetRequest();
            request.open("GET", "../TestLogout.aspx", true);
            request.send();
        }
    }

    function GetRequest() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }
```

Thanks